# Survey data: find weighted means by group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, survey

I would like to find the weighted means of a survey by group (by gender and poverty).

**This is a snippet of my data:**

```
data_in <- read_table2("Q50_1   Q50_2   Q38 Q90 pov gender  wgt id
1   3   Yes 2   High    M   1.3 A
2   4   No  2   Med F   0.4 B
4   2   Yes 4   Low F   1.2 C
3   3   No  2   High    M   0.5 D
1   2   No  4   High    M   0.7 E
2   2   Yes 3   Low F   0.56 F
4   4   Yes 2   Med F   0.9 G
")
```

**This is what I can do to find the weighted means using the survey package:**

Use the survey package:

```
library(survey)
```

Create the survey design:

```
 design <- svydesign(id =~id,
                           weights  = ~wgt,
                           nest = FALSE,
                           data = data_in)
```

Create the vector of vars to be fed into function:

```
vars <- c("Q50_1","Q50_2")
```

Create user function to find the weighted means and weighted N:

```
  create_df_mean <- function(design, vars){
  
  myfun <- function(x){
    means <- svymean(as.formula(paste0('~(', x, ')')),design,  na.rm = T)
    table <- svytable(as.formula(paste0('~(', x, ')')), design)
    results <- list(svymean = means, svytable = table)
    return(results)
  }
  
  
  out <- lapply(vars, myfun)
  lst1 <- lapply(out, function(x) 
    cbind(setNames(as.data.frame(x$svymean), c("mean_weighted", "SE_weighted")),
          weightedN = sum(x$svytable)))
  out1 <- do.call(rbind, lst1)
  out1$question <- row.names(out1)
  row.names(out1) <- NULL
  return(out1)
}
  
  

create_df_mean(design, vars)
```

**This gives me:**

[image]

**However, I want to find the *weighted means by group*, such as this:**

[image]

Any suggestions for how I might achieve this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

We could `split` by the grouping columns into a `list` of datasets, apply the `svydesign` in each of the `list` elements, and then apply the `create_df_mean`

```
lst1 <-  split(data_in, data_in[c('gender', 'pov')], drop = TRUE) 
out_lst <-  lapply(lst1, function(dat) {
   design <- svydesign(id =~id,
                             weights  = ~wgt,
                             nest = FALSE,
                             data = dat)
   

      
    create_df_mean(design, vars)
    }
   )
do.call(rbind, unname(Map(cbind, out_lst, 
          group_level = names(out_lst))))
```

-output

```
#   mean_weighted SE_weighted weightedN question group_level
#1      1.400000   0.4871468      2.50    Q50_1        M.High
#2      2.720000   0.3121969      2.50    Q50_2        M.High
#3      3.363636   0.8677686      1.76    Q50_1         F.Low
#4      2.000000   0.0000000      1.76    Q50_2         F.Low
#5      3.384615   0.8520710      1.30    Q50_1         F.Med
#6      4.000000   0.0000000      1.30    Q50_2         F.Med
```

---

There is also `group_by` functionality in `srvyr`

```
library(srvyr)
data_in %>%
    as_survey_design(ids = id, weights = wgt) %>%
    group_by(gender, pov) %>%
     summarise(Mean = survey_mean(Q50_1 - Q50_2))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   gender [2]
#  gender pov     Mean Mean_se
#  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 F      Low    1.36    0.663
#2 F      Med   -0.615   0.651
#3 M      High  -1.32    0.486
```

Comment: hey akrun i've downvoted this because subsetting a survey dataset prior to constructing the `svydesign` line results in incorrect standard errors  :-(

Comment: @AnthonyDamico It's okay.  I was not confident about this solution though

Comment: @AnthonyDamico if you know the correct way, please post a new solution.  I am not a subject expert in survey design

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without any tidyverse functions, if you use `survey::svyby` and nested `lapply`s to construct your data.frame. This way you can ensure that survey-corrected SEs are calculated for the means by subgroups. There's probably a cleaner solution, but the following works:

```
group_vars <- c("pov","gender")

svyFun <- function(dvs, ivs,design,
         vartype="se",...){
  means <- svyby(make.formula(dvs),
        make.formula(ivs),
        design,
        svymean, ...,
        vartype=vartype)
  totals <- svyby(make.formula("wgt"),
                 make.formula(ivs),
                 design,
                 svytotal, ...,
                 vartype=vartype)
  data.frame(mean_weighted = coef(means),
        SE_weighted = SE(means),
        weightedN = totals[,"wgt"],
        question = dvs,
        group = ivs,
        group_level = means[,ivs])
}
```

`svyby` needs formulas for the DVs and the grouping variables ("IVs"). `survey::svytotal` is used in the second call to svyby to count the sum of the weights `wgt` in each group_level.

We can check the function for one combination of DV and IV first:

```
svyFun("Q50_1","pov", design)
```

Then we can use nested `lapply`s and `do.call("rbind"` to built the data.frame together:

```
mytable <- do.call("rbind", lapply(vars, function(x) 
   do.call("rbind", lapply(group_vars, function(y) 
    svyFun(x, y, design = design, na.rm=T)
    )
    )
   )
)
head(mytable)
mean_weighted SE_weighted weightedN question  group group_level
High       1.400000   0.4296231    2.4300    Q50_1    pov        High
Low        3.363636   0.6627692    1.7536    Q50_1    pov         Low
Med        3.384615   0.6507800    0.9700    Q50_1    pov         Med
F          3.372549   0.4706746    2.7236    Q50_1 gender           F
M          1.400000   0.4296231    2.4300    Q50_1 gender           M
High1      2.720000   0.2753318    2.4300    Q50_2    pov        High
```